# Handling multiple FormCollection keys with same name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, formcollection

How do I handle form collections with same name?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.Editor("StationName", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Station Name" } })
    @Html.Editor("StationURL", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Station URL" } })
    @Html.Editor("Genre", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Station Genre's" } })

    @Html.Editor("StationName", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Station Name" } })
    @Html.Editor("StationURL", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Station URL" } })
    @Html.Editor("Genre", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Station Genre's" } })

    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Upload</button>
    </div>
}
```

I want to add the relevent station details to the database using formcollection, however I want to allow the user to edit multiple fields with the same name at once. E.g. edit name for station one, then edit name for station two and send that to controller.
My wrong controller code so far:

```
if (formCollection != null)
        {
            foreach (var key in formCollection.AllKeys)
            {
                string name = formCollection[key];
                string url = formCollection[key];
                string genre = formCollection[key];

                Station station = new Station
                {
                    StationName = name,
                    StationURL = url,
                    Genre = genre
                };
                  db.Station.Add(station);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You could use a model that has a list of stations that you return and loop through in your controller.